# summoned falling_block banner is invisible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to summon a dynamic block that looks like a banner. This:

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~ ~ {Block:standing_banner,Time:1,NoGravity:1}
```

summons a falling block alright, but it's invisible. I can tell it's there by the shadow, but it doesn't drop an item when it despawns (which is weird, considering that I haven't touched the `DropItem` tag.) Using `Block:wall_banner` does exactly the same thing, and using an invalid block id fails to summon anything. If I omit the `NoGravity` tag, the entity is still invisible until it hits the ground and becomes a block.

This command:

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~ ~ {Block:hopper,Time:1,NoGravity:1}
```

summons a perfectly visible falling block that looks like a hopper and drops as an item when it despawns. They're both data holder blocks, so I have to think it's something specific to banners that makes this happen. Anyone have any thoughts as to what that might be, or how to get around it?

Comment: Which Minecraft version are you playing in? The entity IDs changed recently (I think 1.11), so it's important to know.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using 1.11. The pre-1.11 id was FallingSand, I think.

Comment: I just tested this, with the same results. I also found that chests behaved exactly the same as banners. Aren't chests this weird kind of block called a "Tile entity" or something? I'm not exactly sure. It's probably the same problem.

Comment: They are, but so are all containers, including hoppers. Notably, though, both banners and chests don't take up a full block. brb trying some other blocks with smaller hitboxes... nope, brewing stands work just fine, so that's not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, see [MC-64634](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-64634). Via [Grum's comment](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-64634?focusedCommentId=258129&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-258129), explaining that this will not work for various blocks:

> Using it for anything other than the original block might make it not work.
>
> It doesn't work for the ones without blockmodels.

Since banners do not have a block model, it cannot be rendered with the `falling_block` entity. Hoppers, on the other hand, do have a block model, and so will render properly.

Comment: Well done. Deleted my answer because mine said the same thing and yours is more concise. +1.

Comment: block models, *that* was the difference. Huh, do chests not have a block model either? Live and learn. Thanks for the answer, shame there's no way around it.